# Detecting all packages and modules to create documentation in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have been tasked with creating documentation for a python package at work using Sphinx.

I have the majority of it done however It currently does not recognise the `run.py` module located in the `src/vr_format_conversion/format_conversion` package.

I hope I've explained this well enough. Would appreciate any help at all.

I have used ********* to hide company name...

```
ROOT
|-- src
|   |-- vr_format_conversion
|   |   |-- format_conversion
|   |   |   |   app.py
|   |   |   |   stl_to_vrc.py
|   |   |   |   __init__.py
|   |   |   |-- __pycache__
|   |   |   run.py
|   |   |   __init__.py
|   |   |-- __pycache__
|   |-- format_conversion.egg-info
|   |   __init__.py
|-- docs
|   |   conf.py
|   |-- source
|   |-- \_build
|   |   |-- doctrees
|   |   |   |-- source
|   |   |-- html
|   |   |   |-- source
|   |   |   |-- \_modules
|   |   |   |   |-- *********_format_conversion
|   |   |   |   |   |-- format_conversion
|   |   |   |-- \_sources
|   |   |   |   |-- source
|   |   |   |-- \_static
|   |-- \_static
|   |-- \_templates
```

`conf.py`

```
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# For the full list of built-in configuration values, see the documentation:
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html
import os
import sys

# Add the path to your project's src directory to sys.path
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../src"))

# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#project-information

project = "******* Format Conversion"
copyright = "2024, ********"
author = "********"
release = "0.0.1"

# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#general-configuration

extensions = ["sphinx.ext.todo", "sphinx.ext.viewcode", "sphinx.ext.autodoc"]
# Display todos by setting to True
todo_include_todos = True

templates_path = ["_templates"]
exclude_patterns = ["_build", "Thumbs.db", ".DS_Store"]


# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#options-for-html-output

html_theme = "agogo"
html_static_path = ["_static"]
```

`index.rst`

```
.. *********Format Conversion documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Thu Jan 25 16:19:39 2024.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to ******** Format Conversion's documentation!
======================================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 8
   :caption: Contents:



Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

`modules.rst`

```
src
===

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

   *********_format_conversion.run
```

`src.rst`

```
src package
===========

Subpackages
-----------

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

   src.*********_format_conversion

Module contents
---------------

.. automodule:: src
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

I have spent maybe 4 hours watching youtube, reading the docs, modifying rst files, however I can't seem to grasp the logic here.

Comment: 1) The `toctree` directive in index.rst is empty (it has no content). 2) The `toctree` in modules.rst has `*********_format_conversion.run` as content. For this to make sense, there has to be an RST file called `*********_format_conversion.run.rst`. Is that the case? 3) Having a top-level package that is called `src` is not forbidden, but it looks really strange. I  suppose that `vr_format_conversion` is the actual package name.

Comment: 1. You're right, I'm not entirely sure what to put here.
2. I do not have a *******_format_conversion.run.rst
3. I just substituted the repo name for ROOT in the tree

Comment: 1) I think that you would want to include modules.rst in the `toctree` in index.rst. 2) If you don't have a `*******_format_conversion.run.rst` file then you should see a warning message about that when running Sphinx. 3) Having a project directory called `src` is very common, but `src` itself is not part of the package name. So something like `.. automodule:: src` or `.. automodule:: src.foo.bar` looks just strange.